# AllowEmpty vs NotEmpty

Tags: php, validation, cakephp

New to CakePHP here - I'm going through the documentation on the site, trying to muster up some basic data validation for a model I'm creating. This will likely be the first of many questions I have about CakePHP.

In the [CakePHP Book](http://book.cakephp.org/), the validation rules seem to specify two different methods for making sure that a field isn't empty - [`AllowEmpty`](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1148/allowEmpty), and [`NotEmpty`](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1173/notEmpty).

Question - is there a tangible difference between these two? CakePHP states that validation rules should occur in your model or controller - is one better suited for a model, and the other for a controller? The Book doesn't say anything about this. I'm guessing that one is an older method that's simply still around?

What gives? Should I use a specific one, or both, or does it not matter?

Edit: I decided to check the CakePHP 1.3 [class documentation](http://api13.cakephp.org/file/cake/libs/validation.php) for it (to check the default value of the `allowEmpty` attribute), but it doesn't even show up. It's not in the [source code](http://api13.cakephp.org/view_source/validation/) either...is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Welcome to Cake.  I hope you enjoy it.

This is definitely one of the stranger aspects of Cake.

`notEmpty` is a rule in and of itself.  You can define it in your `$validation` attribute.  You can assign a message for when this validation fails.  You can treat this as if it is any other validation rule.

`allowEmpty` is an option of another validation rule, normally **not** `notEmpty`.  **It is not a validation rule in-and-of-itself.**  This would allow, for example, you to define that a `varchar` field allows an empty string, '', or a string with no more than 20 characters.

Edit:

Here's some code

```
// model validation using 'notEmpty'
$validation = array(
    'fieldName' => array(
        'notEmpty' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty',
            'message' => 'This value may not be left empty!'
        ),
        ... // other rules can go here
    ),
    ... // other fieldName can go here
);


// model validation using 'allowEmpty' to create an optional field
$validation = array(
    'fieldName' => array(
        'maxLength' => array(
             'rule' => array('maxLength', 20),
             'message' => 'This field may only contain 20 characters!',
             'allowEmpty' => true    // we'll also accept an empty string
        ), 
        ... // other rules can go here
    )
    ... // other fieldName can go here
);
```

Comment: I'd thought about this - the rule/message aspect does make sense. However, it seems that `allowEmpty` is set to true by default - or at least, that's the way it looks on the documentation page for it. (The 'if set to false' wording is the reason.) From the documentation, it doesn't seem as though the `allowEmpty` attribute is actually designed to explicitly allow an empty field; it looks like it's created to explicitly _disallow_ it, without supporting any builtin rule attributes (like `on`, `message`, and `last`).

Comment: I'm interested to see where it states that `allowEmpty` is set to `true` by default.  After digging through some source code it appears [on line 2549 of `cake/libs/model/model.php` that `allowEmpty` is set to `null` by default](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/cake/libs/model/model.php)

Comment: +1. Good catch. The wording in the documentation (and the example usage) made it seem as though "true" was the default value - then, when I went to search for it in the validation code, I didn't find it. I have to wonder, though, what the behavior is if nothing is specified.......at any rate, I think that your example is better than the one in the CookBook. Maybe you should try to get it added. :-)

Comment: @lunchmeat317 After I discovered that the default value is `null` I too wondered what the default value actually does.  I'm still trying to do some research on it.  If I figure out an answer I'll edit my post.

Comment: I've been reading through that code you linked to - their code conventions are a little hard to read, but from what I can tell so far...if `allowEmpty` is true and the value is indeed empty, the model will allow an empty value as you stated (by breaking out of the validation `if` blocks early). If `allowEmpty` is false and the value is empty, the model will fail early without running rules. It looks as though if you don't define `allowEmpty`, however, the rules will run, and it won't allow an empty value. From what I can tell, I think it's just path optimization.

Comment: actually, the more I look at the source code, the more I wonder what's really going on. The code really seems a little convoluted, and I think it's because they use multidimensional arrays for validation rules and such instead of objects.

Comment: @lunchmeat317 Perfectly honest, I came into the PHP game late.  I have no concept of PHP4.  I actually dislike Cake for its continued PHP4 support.  BUT, CakePHP 2.0 drops PHP4 support and becomes a *lot* better imo.  For the moment I'm taking a laxidasical approach towards CakePHP 1.3.  I'm interested in how it works, but at the moment I'm actually applying what I learned in Cake to create my own MVC framework.  Just so I can better understand the design pattern.  As CakePHP 2.0 comes closer to going live I'll likely dive headfirst into it again.

Answer (score 0):

I found a case where I had to use 'allowEmpty' => false instead of rule => 'notEmpty'.  I had a form with an upload input (type='file') that had a validation rule of notEmpty, and it kept failing validation, even though the debugger showed the file[] array loaded.  When I removed the 'notEmpty' rule and set allowEmpty => false, it worked, throwing an error when no file was chosen and accepting it when one was selected.
It must have something to do with the value being an array rather than a text value.

Answer (score -1):

Its very simply to make server side validation in cakephp 

Here is code for both validation (noEmpty, maxlength) for the same field.

```
'fieldName' => array(
'rule'    => array('maxLength', 20),
'message' => 'fieldName should be less than 20 characters',
'allowEmpty' => true
),
'fieldName' => array(
    'notEmpty' => array(
        'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
        'message' => 'Please enter field name',
     ),
),
```

Comment: I don't want vote down, but not working, at least with CakePHP 2.5.7